# What is the fundamental difference between a the electromagnetic fields and a gravitational field

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity

I’ve always conceptually thought of a gravitational field and it’s impact on objects and events as an extension to the electromagnetic field, where all matter is charged with the same sign say 0 (since positive and negative are “+” and “-“ I thought 0 made sense) and therefore the more matter the more attractive the object becomes. Why is this logic not true? It’s like if all particles were slightly attracted to each other under the same principals as electromagnetism.

I’m not a physicist clearly but I am someone who likes to study these concepts as much as can. So please feel free to use layman’s and technical definitions. I’m familiar  with GR and QM from an introductory level. I remember that Einstein proved that gravity is a metric of a manifold but don’t remember why it was different than electromagnetism.

Comment: This wikipedia page might interest you. At small velocities the equations of GR almost exactly match up with Maxwells laws, aside from some stray factors of 4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism . At a QFT level, the difference between gravitons and photons all has to do with spin. Photons are spin 1 and gravitons are spin 2. The consequences of this little fact turn out to be enormous.

Comment: You've sorta answered a part of your question - gravity *is* spacetime, while electromagnetism is the theory of a field living *on* spacetime.